# Can not install pykd using pip

Tags: python, pip, pykd

I get an error when I want to install pykd using pip.
The error says:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pykd (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pykd
```

When I try to download the .whl file of pykd and install it with pip, I get this error:

```
ERROR: pykd-0.3.4.15-cp39-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I'm running python 3.11.0 on a Windows 11 64-Bit machine with pip 22.3.1. I tried older versions of pykd but same error.

Can anybody help so I am able to run pykd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pykd-0.3.4.15-**cp39**-none-win_amd64.whl

it is not surprising what this wheel built special for python 3.9, so it can installed only for python 3.9

pykd build for 3.10 or 3.11 does not exsist. And there is no unversal pykd build. Sorry.

I recommend you use 3.8 python with pykd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Python 3.10 & 3.11 wheel build for pykd 0.3.4.15](https://github.com/ivellioscolin/pykd/releases/tag/0.3.4.15%2B). It's forked from [the original repo branch 0.3.2](https://githomelab.ru/pykd/pykd).